# Can not get the phone to accept a password

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id

My 5s is driving me crazy.  I can not open Apple of iCloud because it always rejects my password.  I'll go to Apple or icloud via my computer and change it, and then try opening it a few times.  Always works OK.  BUT, then I try to open it with the phone - and it is rejected for incorrect password.

Comment: your problem is, that your iCloud-password appears to not work on your iPhone?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? Are you sure the email address (Apple ID) that is prompting for a password is the same one that you have tried resetting the password for? Where exactly are you going on your phone that it is asking for the password? (iCloud is not an app. Are you referring to Settings > iCloud?)

Answer (score 1):

Usually two things cause this (or more precisely, one of the two):

- corrupt keychain items or corrupt software install
- wrong date/time on the iOS device

The date/time is far easier to fix, so ensure the clock is accurate within a minute of reality / the PC that's working.

Corruption is harder, so try powering off the device and back on, then try a backup and reset all settings. If that doesn't work, then a restore is next. Once you have a working sign in, you can erase again and then restore the backup or just reload the things you need and forget the backup eventually.